# select and move unique files based on some pattern

Tags: shell-script, rename, mv

I have a list of files on a Linux machine which are differ by some date, so I have to search for unique files and need to place them in some other directory. "Unique" here refers to the name of the file until the second `_`, so `100001_ABC` and `100001_XYZ` in the example below.

```
100001_ABC_25Sep2020_1200-25Sep2020_1300.csv  
100001_XYZ_30Sep2020_1300-30Sep2020_1400.csv  
100001_XYZ_30Sep2020_1400-30Sep2020_1500.csv
```

I want the uniquely named to be placed under this directory:

```
/home/vikrant_singh_rana/uniquefiles/
```

The script should only copy the files below:

```
100001_ABC_25Sep2020_1200-25Sep2020_1300.csv  
100001_XYZ_30Sep2020_1300-30Sep2020_1400.csv
```

Here's my shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
set +o posix
#reading file names into file_array
readarray -t file_array < <(
    cd "/home/vikrant_singh_rana/unzipfiles"
    printf "%s\n" * | cut -d"_" -f2 | cut -d"-" -f1 | sort -u )

#print items of array
printf '%s\n' "${file_array[@]}"


for i in "${file_array[@]}"; do
        #echo $i
        find /home/vikrant_singh_rana/unzipfiles/ -type f -name "*$i*.csv" -exec awk '!seen[$0]++' {} +
done
```

The script can find the unique names correctly, but I can't find how to move them to the other directory.

Comment: Is uniqueness defined only by this substring `25Sep2020`? Do you want always to move the first alphabetically from the uniques?

Comment: uniqueness is defined by ABC & XYZ in my case.

Comment: If you had one more line in your example, XYZ_01Sep2020 and ABC_01Sep2020 it would be clear for all.

Comment: files will be like that only.. it is parsing and selecting unique file correctly. it just that I need to route those selected files to some other directory

Comment: I have accepted one answer only but thank you all for such a wonderful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use arrays, loops or `awk` when there are buildin tools like `uniq` with option `-w` (GNU version)?

```
mv $(ls *csv|uniq -w 10) /home/vikrant_singh_rana/uniquefiles/
```

Comment: Performance doesn't matter obviously. According to the comments to the question, the date should NOT be considered, only ABC, XYZ. As all files have the same start, `-w 10` does the right thing. The file pattern is given, so no whitespaces or control chars will appear. But thank you for the hint about my `sort` mistake.

Comment: welcome. I am not sure still for the uniqueness, perhaps only ABC finally matters, as I see again the comments. And yes, date is not needed, i will modify that, and thank you too.

Comment: Note that although this works fine for the OP's example, it will fail if the file names contain newlines, spaces, or globbing characters.

Comment: @terdo, also if filenames start with `-` (could easily be fixed with `--`) or if some of those csv files are directories (could be fixed with `-d`).

Answer (score 6):

With `zsh`.

```
typeset -A files
for f (*_*_*.csv(.On)) files[${(M)f#*_*_}]=$f
mv -- $files target-directory/
```

The `.` glob qualifier restricts to *regular* files while `On` sorts in reverse order so that in the end the associative array contains the first file in alphabetical order for a given key (here the part up to the second `_`).

Instead of lexical order, you may want to `o`rder by `m`odification time instead (consider that `100001_XYZ_01Oct2020_0000-01Oct2020_0100` would come *before* `100001_XYZ_30Sep2020_2200-30Sep2020_2300` for instance in lexical order), by replacing `On` with `om` (which sorts files from newest to oldest), so that you end up moving the oldest file as opposed to  the one which comes first in lexical order.

Or you could define a sorting order based on the first timestamp in the file name:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
bydate() strftime -rs REPLY %d%b%Y_%H%M ${${REPLY%-*}#*_*_}
```

And use `nO+bydate` instead of `On`/`om`.

With `bash` and GNU tools, you could do something approaching (not restricting to *regular* files, and no sorting by modification time though) with:

```
shopt -s failglob
printf '%s\0' *_*_*.csv | sort -zsmut_ -k1,2 | xargs -r0 mv -t target-dir --
```

(all of `-z`, `-s`, `-r`, `-0`, `-t` are GNU extensions).

The sorting by timestamp extracted from the file names could be done with:

```
printf '%s\0' *_*_*.csv |
                   #  key   year       month      day        HHMM
  LC_ALL=C sort -zt_ -k1,2 -k3.6,3.9n -k3.3,3.5M -k3.1,3.2n -k3.11,3.14n |
  LC_ALL=C sort -zsmut_ -k1,2 |
  xargs -r0 mv -t target-dir
```

If, as the *key*, you want the part between the first and second occurrences of `_`, replace `${(M)f#*_*_}` with `${${f#*_}%%_*}` (or `${${(s[_])f}[2]}`) or `-k1,2` with `-k2,2`.

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution for any filenames:

```bsh
target_dir="path/to/dir"

find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.csv' -print0 | sort -z | awk '
    BEGIN {RS=ORS="\0"; FS=OFS="_"}
    !seen[$2]++' | xargs -r0 echo mv -t "$target_dir" --
```

We use null separator through pipes to protect the filenames, `sort` to get them in alphabetical order and `GNU awk` to exclude duplicates. Test it and if it prints a reasonable move command, remove `echo` to run it.

(Also all the above for null separation are GNU extensions, like `-z` etc)

---

This is simpler for if your filenames are so nice, you can simply do:

```bsh
ls -1 *.csv | awk -F_ '!seen[$2]++' | xargs -d'\n' echo mv -t target/dir --
```

Note the glob fetches the files in alphabetical order.

Comment: could you please also suggest a solution in which I have to change a very little in original script

Comment: I added one more solution, I wouldn't use arrays for this, I hope it is helpful and readable.

Answer (score 4):

I would just use an array to hold the names you've seen and move only the "new" names:

```
declare -A seen=()
name_seen='seen[$name]++' # work around to avoid ACE vulnerability
for i in /home/vikrant_singh_rana/unzipfiles/*_*_*; do 
    name=${i##*/} # remove directory part
    name=${name%"_${name#*_*_}"} # retain first two fields
    (( name_seen )) || mv -- "$i" /home/vikrant_singh_rana/uniquefiles/
done
```

Comment: I like this approach also.. it's very close to the original script. Thanks

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas D'oh! Of course, thanks. I was testing with local files and only added the path before posting. I changed it to use `${i##*/}` instead, which should be safe.

Comment: It also won't work if `$name` contains `]` or ``\`` characters (that's actually a command injection vulnerability, like when there's a file called `x] + a[$(reboot)`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas oh man, the `mv` was wrong in any case, that should have been `mv -- $i` not `mv -- $name`. I missed that! And you're right about the `\ ` and `\]`, the latter is particularly likely to be found in  media file names. I changed to using `basename` instead, that should be safe, right?

Comment: See edit for how to avoid the ACE. Also removed `cut`. Can't use line-based utilities on file names. `basename` doesn't help here. The problem is with `(( seen[$name]++ ))` where `$name` is expanded before the arithmetic expression is evaluated.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks @StéphaneChazelas! I had always thought that `${foo%bar}` style expansions couldn't be nested! Nice!

Comment: It's not really nesting (like in `zsh`'s `${${var#x}%y}`), just that there are parameter expansions in the pattern used in `${var%pattern}`. `${var%"${var#pattern}"}` is a common idiom to return the leading part of `$var` that matches the pattern.